Why do scikit-learn predict(X) methods accept a 2D matrix rather than a 1D vector?
Does anyone know why the predict(X) methods of scikit-learn classifiers and regressors expect input X to be a 2D array (matrix) rather than a 1D array (vector)? I'm just curious about the history of the design.
With the existing design, if you want to predict for a 1D vector, you can easily convert the 1D vector to a 2D matrix by using the NumPy reshape() function, or using double-square bracket syntax, or probably some other ways that don't come immediately to mind.
I suspect that the reason the existing scikit-learn design accepts a 2D matrix as input is to avoid the painfully slow explicit for-loops you'd need if predict(x) methods accepted 1D vectors and you wanted to make predictions for multiple inputs stored as rows of a matrix.
But this is just a guess. Does anyone know why the design of scikit-learn predict(X) signatures decided to accept a 2D matrix rather than a 1D vector?
Again, the predict(X) design of accepting a 2D matrix rather than a 1D vector doesn't matter, I'm just curious.

Yes it is to make use of efficient matrix operations, and as you said the avoidance of for loops (especially on GPUs). For online request serving, in high QPS systems, requests are batched and inference is done on the whole batch to improve overall throughput. Another common use of predict is to do offline evaluation where by design you want predictions computed on a large set of examples at once.
This is a good answer that talks about why matrix operations tend to be more efficient than for loops.
